#  convert text to speech in obj c for an iphone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How to implement text to speech functionality in iPad ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5978308/how-to-implement-text-to-speech-functionality-in-ipad)
>   [Text to speech on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/416064/text-to-speech-on-iphone)

converting text to speech in `Objective-c`, can anyone suggest  an API or sample code for this?

Thanx in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a look at these:

> In short, there are no APIs for recording phone calls or converting text to speech. You will need to create a speech recognition engine. I suspect the iPhone hardware will not be powerful enough to handle that type of processing though.

1. [APIs for converting Voice/Audio data in to text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1681990/apis-for-converting-voice-audio-data-in-to-text)
2. [API for Voice recognition in among group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1651051/api-for-voice-recognition-in-among-group)
3. [iPhone speech recognition API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1121548/iphone-speech-recognition-api)

Reference: [Convert the voice to text in iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3626108/convert-the-voice-to-text-in-iphone/3627711#3627711)